# Is the Strategy design pattern suitable for logic based on string comparisons?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

As of now my code has multiple if else statements branching, depending upon the value of a string. i.e.

```
if(input == "condition1")
{
    // Some logic
}
else if(input =="condition1")
{
    // Some other logic
}
```

I'm planning to use the Strategy Pattern. Is this the right approach? If yes, how can I create the correct Concrete Strategy object depending on the condition?

Thanks

Comment: you can read this article http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx or this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/346873/Understanding-and-Implementing-the-Strategy-Patter

Answer (score 3):

In the code example you have provided, Strategy is not going to get you away from the if conditions you already have. You would end up needing a Factory to create your strategy objects as follows:

```
static class StrategyFactory
{
    static IStrategy CreateStrategy(string input)
    {
        if (input == "condition1")
        {
            return new StrategyForCondition1();
        }
        else if (input == "condition2")
        {
            return new StrategyForCondition2();
        }
    }
}
```

This is why I would not recommend Strategy for your case.

A very elegant alternative solution is to use a Dictionary where the key is the input string value and the Action is the contents of the if statement:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    {"condition1", () => Console.WriteLine("condition1")},
    {"condition2", NameOfMethodThatHandlesCondition2}
};
```

Now, the beauty of this solution is that you use it with only 1 line of code:

```
actions[input];
```

See examples here: http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/10/refactoring-a-switch-statement/

One issue in your code sample is that you are comparing to a string... which could be any possible value. If possible, create an enum instead that represents all possible conditions. This will prevent coming up against a string value that you are not anticipating.

Comment: +1 for using a factory. This way the responsibility of determining which strategy to be used is in a separate class. Also, great suggestion on using an enum instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great site with some really good examples of different Pattern types in C#.

[Strategy Design Patterns in C# and VB](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx#_self1)

```
// Strategy pattern -- Structural example
using System;

namespace DoFactory.GangOfFour.Strategy.Structural
{
  /// <summary>
  /// MainApp startup class for Structural
  /// Strategy Design Pattern.
  /// </summary>
  class MainApp
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into console application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
      Context context;

      // Three contexts following different strategies
      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyA());
      context.ContextInterface();

      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyB());
      context.ContextInterface();

      context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyC());
      context.ContextInterface();

      // Wait for user
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Strategy' abstract class
  /// </summary>
  abstract class Strategy
  {
    public abstract void AlgorithmInterface();
  }


  /// <summary>  
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class ConcreteStrategyA : Strategy
  {
    public override void AlgorithmInterface()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Called ConcreteStrategyA.AlgorithmInterface()");
    }
  }

  /// <summary>  
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class ConcreteStrategyB : Strategy
  {
    public override void AlgorithmInterface()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Called ConcreteStrategyB.AlgorithmInterface()");
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class ConcreteStrategyC : Strategy
  {
    public override void AlgorithmInterface()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Called ConcreteStrategyC.AlgorithmInterface()");
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Context' class
  /// </summary>
  class Context
  {
    private Strategy _strategy;

    // Constructor
    public Context(Strategy strategy)
    {
      this._strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void ContextInterface()
    {
      _strategy.AlgorithmInterface();
    }
  }
}

Output
Called ConcreteStrategyA.AlgorithmInterface()
Called ConcreteStrategyB.AlgorithmInterface()
Called ConcreteStrategyC.AlgorithmInterface()
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use a switch?

```
switch (input) {
  case "condition1": 
    // do stuff
    break;
  case "condition2":
    // do stuff....
    break;
  default:
    // default stuff
    break;
}
```

Or failing that use a `Dictionary<string,Action>`

```
var actions=new Dictionary<string,Action> { { "condition1", () => {code}}, {"condition2",) => {code}};
```

Then..

```
if (actions.ContainsKey(input)) actions[input]();
```

Comment: Would be nice if you actually added comments rather than just marking down answers..